# Make: Command not found, but command exists?

Tags: linux, path, makefile, slackware

So I have a make file which uses `arm-eabi-none-xxx` commands, but when I run make I get a "Command not Found" error:

```
bash-4.2$ make
arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/mailbox.s -o build/mailbox.o
make: arm-none-eabi-as: Command not found
make: *** [build/mailbox.o] Error 127
```

Weird bit, is the command exists and is in my path (the following is in the same directory as the makefile):

```
bash-4.2$ arm-none-eabi-as --version
GNU assembler (Sourcery G++ Lite 2008q3-66) 2.18.50.20080215
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-eabi'.
```

And I can run the command that make is running:

```
bash-4.2$ arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/mailbox.s -o build/mailbox.o
bash-4.2$ ls build/
README  mailbox.o
```

So. I read that make uses the shell to execute commands if `./` is in the current path, so I've tried that but no good. Originally I couldn't run `arm-none-eabi-as` at all as it's a 32-bit binary and I'm running on a 64 bit system (Slackware 14.0) [but I followed the instructions here to install the 32-bit libraries](http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=slackware%3amultilib) etc..

So the question... what stupid schoolboy mistake am I making?

Comment: You can add path to `arm-none-eabi-as` to PATH in the Makefile. Or, specify the full path.

Comment: SO it doesn't use my current path which includes the directory that's in?

Comment: @LaceyStr: By default, it does; look for an assignment to `PATH` in your `Makefile` and check that the shell it uses (`/bin/sh` unless it assigns to `SHELL`) is the same as your interactive shell.

Comment: I've temporarily fixed it using the full path to the command. Makefile has neither `SHELL` nor any `PATH` assignment though.

Comment: What does `type arm-none-eabi-as` tell you?

Comment: `bash-4.2$ type arm-none-eabi-as` gives: `arm-none-eabi-as is /home/matt/bin/arm/arm-none-eabi-as`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you run 'make' as sudo, or root? In that case, it doesn't work for me.
What I had to do was mkdir a 'build' folder, and simply run 'make'. It worked.