# make error 127(command not found), but the command exists (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I tried this solution, but it didn't work.

[Make: Command not found, but command exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000303/make-command-not-found-but-command-exists)

I have the Makefile, added the appropriate path to ./bashrc.

When I try the same command as in Makefile by actually typing it in the terminal, it perfectly works.

But when I use 'make', error 127 occurs.

Comment: Did you open a  new shell after adding to ./bashrc?

Comment: Yes, I opened a new shell and tried several times but it didn't work.